# Access view of included xml layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I need to access the view present in a.xml layout included in another b.xml layout.
For example,
This is a.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/xyz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XYZ" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And, in b.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/a_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        layout="@layout/a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/xyz"
        android:text="Show me below xyz" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have to do it in xml code, because if I do it in Java it must be after setContentView() and then setting LayoutParams of TextView 'label' wont take effect.

I guess, everyone understand what I am trying to ask. Waiting for good replies.

Thanks all.

Image on the right is what I am trying to achieve and left one is what I am getting with the current code.

[image: This is what I am getting with the current xml code]
[image: This is what I am trying to do]

Comment: If I've guessed it, then access it by its id: `findViewById(R.id.label)`

Comment: You are right, I can access it using findViewById(R.id.label). But I can't do this android:layout_below="@id/xyz"

Comment: Have you tried to run the app with this `android:layout_below="@id/xyz"`? Compiler doesn't deny do so.

Comment: Compiler didn't deny, but android:layout_below="@id/xyz" didn't work either.

Comment: use linearlayout in b.xml and set orientation vertical.

Answer (score 3):

In b.xml, you should correct:

```
android:layout_below="@id/xyz"
```

to

```
android:layout_below="@id/a_layout"
```

And then you can use it in your code (Here I place it in onCreate):

```
setContentView(R.layout.b);    
((Button)findViewById(R.id.xyz)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("clicked on XYZ button");
        }
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work either see in b.xml included layout has android:layout_height="fill_parent" so its natural that TextView will not show.

Comment: @Trickster Oh, i forgot re-check it - It must has android:layout_height="wrap_content" Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in accessing the `View` of included layout, but in the fact that you cannot achieve this layouts "overlapping". Let me explain: if you add some more views below the button in your `a.xml` and then try to place some view in your `b.xml` just below the button then it would make the views from `b.xml` overlap views from `a.xml`, however this has not been implemented in Android (yet?). So, the only thing you can do is to put `android:layout_below="@id/a_layout"` as @Hoàng Toản suggested.

P.S. You may observe same behavior with this `a` + `b` layouts combination:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/xyz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XYZ" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/xyz"
        android:text="Show me below xyz" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, the layouts in my app are very different from the examples, that's why, I can not combine both of them.
These are only two layouts for example, but in my project, there are 15 layouts which are including a.xml and a.xml is not simple as example one, it is the header of the each activity.

Comment: As I've noted, you can't get such sophisticated structure with current Android SDK - `a` + `b` combination illustrates it (there is no `include` element, but still same behavior, see?).